# Can not call one function from another function using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i was trying to call one function from another function using angular.js but it gave the following error.

```
TypeError: $scope.addwithDept is not a function
```

I am explaining my code below.

> Rolecontroller.js:

```
var dashboard = angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('roleController', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Add";
    $scope.addUserRoleData = function () {
        if ($('#addProfileData')[0].defaultValue == 'Add') {
            if ($scope.showDept) {
                $scope.addwithDept();
            } else {
                $scope.addwithOutDept();
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.addWithDept = function () {
        console.log('hii');
    }
})
```

The error is coming at function inside the if statement.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Satya following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lt7aP/1197/) simulates your issue.

Comment: It probably has to do with the way you're attaching controller to DOM, [here's a simplified version](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/5o6sj67f/) if you want to play with it

Comment: See [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lt7aP/1199/), by moving the function up has solved problem, Thanks @Rajesh for fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Move the function `scope.addWithDept` above the functions which are calling it.

The function when defined as `$scope.functionName = function() {...` is the function expression. The function is not yet defined, so calling it results in `fn is not a function` error. This function is not like function declaration. Function declaration is hoisted to the top whereas function expressions are not.

```
var dashboard = angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('roleController', function ($scope, $http, $state) {

    $scope.buttonName = "Add";

    // Moved this function here
    $scope.addWithDept = function () {
        console.log('hii');
    };

    $scope.addUserRoleData = function () {
        if ($('#addProfileData')[0].defaultValue == 'Add') {
            if ($scope.showDept) {
                $scope.addwithDept();
            } else {
                $scope.addwithOutDept();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @satya Can you please create jsfiddle and also add HTML in question

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare  $scope.addWithDept function before $scope.addUserRoleData function

```
var dashboard = angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('roleController', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Add";

    $scope.addWithDept = function () {
        console.log('hii');
    }
    $scope.addUserRoleData = function () {
        if ($('#addProfileData')[0].defaultValue == 'Add') {
            if ($scope.showDept) {
                $scope.addwithDept();
            } else {
                $scope.addwithOutDept();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: This is exact duplicate of my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33052614/2025923, didn't you see that, I've posted it about 45 minutes ago

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't see that.

Comment: Thanks to all for sharing their solution.But mistake was in my side.I found it and corrected it.Please see the two function name.it is total different thats why the error was coming.